# How to create an ISA Hierarchy where only one subtype is allowed to exist in SQL?

Tags: sql, primary-key, hierarchy

Say for example I have a table for Person. This table looks as such:

```
create table Person (id int not null primary key, 
FirstName varchar(20) not null,
LastName varchar(20) not null
)
```

The ISA Hierarchy has 2 extended types, Staff and Student, underneath it as follows:

```
create table Staff (
id int not null primary key references Person(id),
department varchar(20) not null
)
create table Student (
id int not null primary key references Person(id),
course varchar(20) not null
)
```

From this current implementation, I could possibly create a Student entry and Staff entry both related to the same Person ID. I'm trying to make it exclusive so that a Person is only either allowed to be Staff or Student but I'm a bit lost on how to do that.

Any input is appreciated !

Comment: One way to achieve this is via BEFORE INSERT Triggers on the Staff & Student tables. And let those triggers check if a flag field in the Person table is already filled in for the ID. F.e. a field named "Type". Also with AFTER INSERT Triggers that update the flag field in Persons.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, somebody could be both a staff member and a student, but you are describing a situation in which somebody may be only one or the other.  Consequently the 'staff or student' category is a single-valued attribute of the person, and therefore this category value should be stored in the `Person` table.  To constrain the child tables, the `Person` table should have an additional unique index on both `id` and that category column, and your `Staff` and `Student` tables then should also include this column, and use it in the foreign key back to `Person`, and have a check constraint to ensure that only the appropriate value (and therefore, category of person) is entered into each of the child tables.